# Sets Theory Disproof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have to disprove the statement:
For all sets $S$, if $S$ is a subset of the Natural Numbers, then there must exists some $t ∈ S$ such that $|t|\ge1$ Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\varnothing \subset \mathbb{N}$ yet there is no $t \in \varnothing$ satisfying any property.